# Dark Sky API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-geocoding-api, weather-api

I am using Dark Sky API to create a weather app. I am stuck at one point. I am trying to make an API call of Time Machine. The format given in the documentation is :https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/[latitude],[longitude],[time]

Now I am making a call : 
url + apiKey + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude + weathertime +"?&callback=?";

url : https://api.darksky.net/forecast/
and latitude and longitude are passed.

Now the problem is it is working without "," after longitude and weather time being the supplied date timestamp, it is always giving me the data of current day.

Can anyone tell me how to properly use DarkSkyAPI Time Machine request to get the defined date data?

Comment: Have you checked what `console.log(longitude + weathertime)` outputs? I suspect it to be either an integer or float, containing the sum of two numbers. Maybe show us what's in the variables, without the API key ofcourse.

Comment: @BerryM.   Ihave checked but if that was the case the API should give me an error as API requires latitude,longitude,time and the major part is it is giving me data without the "," between longitude and time.

Comment: Well, that still leaves the suggesting of giving us a codesnippet unanswered. Here on SO code snippets save lives :)